# mongoose cant display private message data

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose, mean-stack

I am pretty new with mongoose & node.js and I am having an issue with displaying my users messages privately.

The message recipient, sender and message content is stored in the database.

but when I want to see the message's between two users, the messages between two users are displayed on every user messages tab!.
(developing in MEAN stack environment)

**The Problem:** https://i.imgur.com/qfDlMml.mp4

**Messages Schema:**

```
var messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  id: {
    type: Number,
  },

  senderId: {
    type: Number
  },

  senderUsername: {
    type: String
  },

  recipientId: {
    type: Number
  },

  recipientUsername: {
    type: String
  },

  content: {
    type: String,
    required:true
  },

  dateRead: {
    type: Date
  },

  messageSent: {
    type: Date
  },

  senderDeleted: {
    type: Boolean
  },

  recipientDeleted: {
    type: Boolean
  }
},
  {
    collection: 'messages',
    timestamps: true
  },
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Messages', messageSchema)
```

**User route:**

```
//Get Message Of User
usersRoute.route("/messages/thread/:username/:senderUsername").get((req, res) => {

    Messages.find(({ data: { "$in" : [req.params.senderUsername,req.params.username]} }, (error, data) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error)
            throw error;
          }
  
          res.json(data);
  
        }))

  })
```

**messages.service:**

```
  getMessageThread(username: string,sender:string) {
    return this.http.get<Message[]>(`${AUTH_API}messages/thread/${username}/${sender}`);
  }
```

**member-messages.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Message } from 'src/app/models/message';
import { User } from 'src/app/models/user';
import { AccountService } from 'src/app/services/account.service';
import { MessageService } from 'src/app/services/message.service';
import { Observable, take } from 'rxjs'
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MembersService } from 'src/app/services/members.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-member-messages',
  templateUrl: './member-messages.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./member-messages.component.css']
})

export class MemberMessagesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() username: string;
  @Input() messages: Message[];
  user: User;
  member: any;
  currentUser$: Observable<User | null>;
  messageContent: string;

  constructor(
 private messageService: MessageService,
 private accountService: AccountService,
 private route: ActivatedRoute,
 private memberService: MembersService
) {
    this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(x => {

      this.currentUser$ = this.accountService.currentUser$;
      this.user = x as User;

    });
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    const username = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('username') as string;
    this.memberService.getMember(username).subscribe(member => { 
    this.member = member;
    });
  }

  sendMessage(form: NgForm) {
    this.messageService.sendMessage(this.username, this.messageContent, this.user)
      .subscribe((message) => {
        this.messages.push(message as Message);
  
        form.reset();
      })
  }
}
```

member-messages.html:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
  
      <ng-container *ngIf="messages && messages.length; else noMessages">
        <ul class="chat">
          <li *ngFor="let message of messages.slice().reverse()">

            <span class="chat-img float-right">
              <img class="rounded-circle" *ngIf="message.senderUsername && member.username == message.recipientUsername" src="{{user.profile_img || './assets/user.jpg'}}"> <span *ngIf="message.senderUsername && member.username == message.recipientUsername" style="color:red"> {{message.senderUsername}}</span> <img class="rounded-circle" *ngIf="message.recipientUsername && member.username != message.recipientUsername " src="{{member.profile_img || './assets/user.jpg'}}"><span *ngIf="message.recipientUsername && member.username != message.recipientUsername" style="color:green"> {{member.username}}</span>
            </span>
            <div class="chat-body" >
              <p >{{message.content}}</p>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </ng-container>
  
      <ng-template #noMessages>No messages Yet... say hi bu using the message box bellow</ng-template>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <form #messageForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sendMessage(messageForm)" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input
          name="messageContent"
          required
          [(ngModel)]="messageContent"
          type="text"
          class="form-control input-sm"
          placeholder="Send a private message">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button [disabled]="!messageForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-radius:0px 5px 5px 0px"type="submit"> Send </button>
  
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to find a work around, created another query only this time the senderUser value will be the recipient username and recipientUsername value as the senderUsername :

```
  const query2 = {
    senderUsername: req.params.username,
    recipientUsername: req.params.senderUsername,
  };
```

Find with both quires while using `$or:[query,query2]`.

the following example **worked**:

```
usersRoute
.route("/messages/thread/:username/:senderUsername")
.get(async (req, res) => {
  const query = {
    senderUsername: req.params.senderUsername,
    recipientUsername: req.params.username,
  };
  const query2 = {
    senderUsername: req.params.username,
    recipientUsername: req.params.senderUsername,
  };

  const messages = await Messages.find({$or:[query,query2]}).exec();

  console.log(messages);
  res.json(messages);
});
```

Could there be a better way to do it? I would really like to understand this better.

Thank you @Paweł Antyporowicz for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to query for the `data` field but this field does not exist in your data model.
Solution is to ask data model for messages which contain `senderUsername` and `recipientUsername` in the database.

```
usersRoute
  .route("/messages/thread/:username/:senderUsername")
  .get(async (req, res) => {
    const query = {
      senderUsername: req.params.senderUsername,
      recipientUsername: req.params.username,
    };

    const messages = await Messages.find(query).exec();

    res.json(messages);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, now though I cant see the recipient messages, I can only see the message I sent as the logged in user.

Comment: could you help? It only displays now the messages I sent. If I logged with KariRollins and I go to BarberLeon's chat, I can only see the message KariRollins sent to BarberLeon, and If I will login with BarberLeon, I will only see the messages BarberLeon sent to KariRollins.